# how to fill data in text field in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, edit, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

when I am signing up using this time user has to fill 4 forms and at the end of the gets all the details displayed in last display form when I click on particular form edit button it will redirect back to the form field and then I can edit it. I hope you understand the question. can anyone help me? thank you in advance.

I'll explain to you using this image. in this image, there is on business details container when I click on the edit of this container. it will get back to the business details page and i can able to edit these fields.

Here is the image

[image]

Comment: You can use PageView for this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

Comment: thank you but I've added the page now is it possible to replace all pages with page view???

Comment: Yes, with some minor modifications in your code you can easily use your pages to PageView

Comment: Can you please help me?? i'll share my code. just give hint using one page and rest i will do it.

Comment: Check Sample page view example for your refrence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219525/how-can-i-go-to-the-page-when-i-click-the-button-in-pageview/58220179#58220179

Comment: Sorry sir, I've seen your example but I still didn't understand how page view works for me.

Comment: Why don't you stay in the same page and when tapping the edit button just make the text fields editable?

Answer (score 1):

For a simpler solution, you can store the data a `Map<String, dynamic>` (can also be `Map>.

On every TextFormField's `onSave` or `onChange`, you can set the value of the `Map`.
Example:

```
TextFormField(
  // We set the initial value of the text field here
  initialValue: _map['firstName'] ?? '',
  onSave: (String value) {
    _map['firstName'] = value;
  }
)
```

Then you will pass the `Map` to the next page/screen.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
   // We pass the Map to the next screen
   builder: (_) => MyNextScreen(data: _map),
  ),
);
```

If you use the `pushReplacement` and want to go to the business details route/screen, then just past the `Map` again.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
   // We pass the Map to the next screen
   builder: (_) => BusinessDetailScreen(data: _map),
  ),
);
```

**UPDATE**

`TextField` doesn't have the `initialValue` property, can you try using `TextFormField`?

Here is the example how to have a filled (initial value) `TextFormField`

```
TextFormField(
          // We set the value of the TextFormField
          initialValue: _map['business_name'],
          onSaved: (value) {
            _map['business_name'] = value;
          },
        )
```

Comment: in the first phase, I am already filling this form and then click on the next button then it will show me the data as in the above image when i click on that edit icon it will get back to redirect me the appropriate page.

Comment: thanks but what if there is Dropdown, imagepicker,??

Comment: for dropdown, you just need to pass the `value`. DropdownButton have a parameter `value` which you can pass something like `_map['business_type']`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand want you want to accomplish, that when a user tap the edit(pencil) icon the app navigates to another page where the user could change the data fields, is it?

To send data to a router destiny constructor you can use:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    return ResultPage(
      bmiResult: calc.calculateBMI(),
      resultText: calc.getResult()
    );
  }),
);

//In the destiny you can recover the information:
class ResultPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ResultPage( {@required this.bmiResult,@required this.resultText});
  final String bmiResult;
  final String resultText;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
```